# How to position and align a matplotlib figure legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a figure with two subplots as 2 rows and 1 column. I can add a nice looking figure legend with

```
fig.legend((l1, l2), ['2011', '2012'], loc="lower center", 
           ncol=2, fancybox=True, shadow=True, prop={'size':'small'})
```

However, this legend is positioned at the center of the **figure** and not below the center of the **axes** as I would like to have it. Now, I can obtain my axes coordinates with

```
axbox = ax[1].get_position()
```

and in theory I should be able to position the legend by specifying the *loc* keyword with a tuple:

```
fig.legend(..., loc=(axbox.x0+0.5*axbox.width, axbox.y0-0.08), ...)
```

This works, **except** that the legend is left aligned so that *loc* specifies the left edge/corner of the legend box and not the center. I searched for keywords such as *align*, *horizontalalignment*, etc., but couldn't find any. I also tried to obtain the "legend position", but legend doesn't have a *get_position()* method. I read about *bbox_to_anchor* but cannot make sense of it when applied to a figure legend. This seems to be made for axes legends.

Or: should I use a shifted axes legend instead? But then, why are there figure legends in the first place? And somehow it must be possible to "center align" a figure legend, because *loc="lower center"* does it too.

Thanks for any help,

Martin

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In this case, you can either use axes for figure `legend` methods. In either case, `bbox_to_anchor` is the key.  As you've already noticed `bbox_to_anchor` specifies a tuple of coordinates (or a box) to place the legend at.  When you're using `bbox_to_anchor` think of the `location` kwarg as controlling the horizontal and vertical alignment.

The difference is just whether the tuple of coordinates is interpreted as axes or figure coordinates.

As an example of using a figure legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

# The key to the position is bbox_to_anchor: Place it at x=0.5, y=0.5
# in figure coordinates.
# "center" is basically saying center horizontal alignment and 
# center vertical alignment in this case
fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 0.5], 
           loc='center', ncol=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

As an example of using the axes method, try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

# The key to the position is bbox_to_anchor: Place it at x=0.5, y=0
# in axes coordinates.
# "upper center" is basically saying center horizontal alignment and 
# top vertical alignment in this case
ax1.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 0], 
           loc='upper center', ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.25)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Joe. This is clarifying. Upon further thinking, I guess the answer to my original question should be: "if you want to use axes coordinates, use axes.legend." Yet - out of curiosity, I still wonder if the loc keyword is the only way to control the text alignment in a legend box? In many other matplotlib objects, you can extract the patches, lines, etc. (see for example the boxplot documentation), and modify their properties. This doesn't seem to work for (text objects in) legends, at least not straightforwardly. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

This is a very good question and the accepted answer indicates the key (i.e. `loc` denotes alignment and `bbox_to_anchor` denotes position). I have also tried some codes and would like to stress **the importance of `bbox_transform` property** that may sometimes needs to be explicitly specified to achieve desired effects. Below I will show you my findings on `fig.legend`. `ax.legend` should be very similar as `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` works the same way.

When using the default setting, we will have the following.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,4), sharex=True)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], loc='lower center', ncol=2)
```

[image]

This is basically satisfactory. But it could be easily found that the legend overlays with the x-axis ticklabels of `ax2`. This is the problem that will become even severe when `figsize` and/or `dpi` of the figure changes, see the following.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,12), sharex=True, facecolor='w', gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.01})

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], loc='lower center', ncol=2)
```

[image]

So you see there are big gaps between `ax2` and the legend. That's not what we want. Like the questioner, we would like to manually control the location of the legend. First, I will use the 2-number style of `bbox_to_anchor` like the answer did.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,12), sharex=True, facecolor='w', gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.01})

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

axbox = ax2.get_position()

# to place center point of the legend specified by loc at the position specified by bbox_to_anchor.
fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], loc='center', ncol=2,
           bbox_to_anchor=[axbox.x0+0.5*axbox.width, axbox.y0-0.05])
```

[image]

Almost there! But it is totally wrong as the center of the legend is not at the center of what we really mean! The key to solving this is that we need to explicitly inform the `bbox_transform` as `fig.transFigure`. [By default None, the Axes' transAxes transform will be used](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html). This is understandable as most of the time we will use `ax.legend()`.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,12), sharex=True, facecolor='w', gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.01})

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

axbox = ax2.get_position()

# to place center point of the legend specified by loc at the position specified by bbox_to_anchor!
fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], loc='center', ncol=2,
           bbox_to_anchor=[axbox.x0+0.5*axbox.width, axbox.y0-0.05], bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

[image]

As an alternative, we can also use a 4-number style `bbox_to_anchor` for `loc`. This is essentially specify a real box for the legend and `loc` really denotes alignment! The default `bbox_to_anchor` should just be `[0,0,1,1]`, meaning the entire figure box! The four numbers represent `x0,y0,width,height`, respectively. It is very similar to [specifying a cax for a shared colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph/56900830#56900830)! Hence you can easily change the `y0` just a little bit lower than `axbox.y0` and adjust `loc` accordingly.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,12), sharex=True, facecolor='w', gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.01})

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
line1, = ax1.plot(x, np.cos(3*x), color='red')
line2, = ax2.plot(x, np.sin(4*x), color='green')

axbox = ax2.get_position()

# to place center point specified by loc at the position specified by bbox_to_anchor!
fig.legend([line1, line2], ['yep', 'nope'], loc='lower center', ncol=2,
           bbox_to_anchor=[0, axbox.y0-0.05,1,1], bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

[image]