# Matplotlib: Intelligent figure scale / legend location

Tags: python, matplotlib

Some code gives me the following `matplotlib` figure:

[image: standard output]

Unfortunately, the figure size is fixed and hence on the top right, the legend and the lines overlap. Is there any way to have the legend not stack on top of the lines?

I am aware that legend allows `ax2.legend(loc=0)`, where `0` will put it into the "best" location. However, with two y axis as here, this will stack both legends on top of each other - not really the best allocation.

My next best try would be to "scale up" the figure, as manually done with an interactive graph, where I have only scaled up both axis:

[image: scaled figure]

Doing this with the "real" figure scale requires iterated "trying numbers and checking how far it goes" procedure - which may need to be redone if the graph changes. Is there any way of having matplotlib compute the scale "intelligently"?

Comment: I remember a very similar question just yesterday, about intelligent positioning of the legend not to overlap the graphs, but I can't find it now...

Answer (score 1):

If the best location `plt.legend(loc='best')` fails, try putting the legend outside of the plot:

```
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), borderaxespad=0)
```

You can scale only legend, not the whole plot. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404066/4658852)

More on legends [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101700/moving-matplotlib-legend-outside-of-the-axis-makes-it-cutoff-by-the-figure-box) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894345/how-to-position-and-align-a-matplotlib-figure-legend#13962752).